# Skill Matrix using SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, reporting-services, reports

I want to create the Skill Matrix in SharePoint 2013. How to create the skill matrix using SharePoint List?

- Matrix that contains all the development skills of the Employee in different departments.
- Using the Data from list, I can take the Periodic reports of Employee Skills

What can I use, SSRS Report or create a custom web Part?

Comment: I was thinking that this was really two questions not one. The answer is maybe to both, but will that solve the business problem? I think you should start with a team site and then think about adding a term list for the skills, allowing people to add their own terms. What is your periodic report meant to achieve? That is the important question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully created the Skill Matrix using Kendo Grid UI. Populate Kendo Grid by using list as data soucre 
The colors indicate the Skill Level of the employee.
[image]